# Is there a way to check for typos in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have...

```
male = "male"
female = "female"

role = input("Are you a male or female? ")

if role == male:
    print("male")

if role == female:
    print("female")
```

Results:
Are you a male or female? male
male
Are you a male or female? female
female
Are you a male or female? nale
(nothing returned)

*If you misspell a word in your input response is there a way for your code to print something else?

I've tried to adding new else statements, a new 'typo' variable, then add an elif statement.

ex:

```
male = "male"
female = "female"
typo = not "cat" or "dog"

role = input("Are you a male or female? ")

if role == male:
    print("male")
elif typo:
    print("over")

if role == female:
    print("female")
elif typo:
    print("over")
```

Results:
Are you a male or female? male
male
over
Are you a male or female? female
over
female
Are you a male or female? nale
over
over

Comment: You might want to look into [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

Comment: Are you looking to look for only a specific set of typos, or do you just want to only allow certain values?

Comment: I'm just looking to have it print "over" if the value "cat" or "dog" is not entered for the question. @G.Anderson

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Okay thanks, I will

Comment: Warning: `typo = not "cat" or "dog"` doesn't do what you think it does. Inspect `typo` right after running that.

Comment: @Chris Is setting typo = to variables the same thing as setting it = to text?

Comment: I second fuzzywuzzy – it gives you the number of edits necessary to change one word to another. Thus, `"nale" -> "male"` is only a single change, as well as `"mael"`. But with your small choice of options it cannot handle `"emale"`.

Comment: @usr2564301 is there no way to just have python say if user input isn't cat or dog or male of female... then print or do this... because like what if someone where to type "jhsdfdsjfsdfjsffsdf" or something dumb..

Comment: @hackerboi To attempt and simplify it. Nonempty strings in python are considered truthy. The statement `'cat' or 'dog'` equates to `'cat'` since it's checking a conditional where both are present. It looks at `'cat'` first and sees it's present so it hands that back to you. `not 'cat' or 'dog'` equates to the opposite of that so it equates to `'dog'`.

Comment: So essentially `typo = not "cat" or "dog"` is saying `typo = "dog"`.

Comment: You are asking about *typos* but it seems you want a whitelist of allowed answers only.

Comment: role = " "
valid_roles = ['male', 'female']

role = input("Are you a male or female? ")
if role in valid_roles:
    print(role)
else:
    print("over")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correct here is something you can do:

```
your_input = 'male'
valid_inputs = ['cat', 'dog']
if your_input in valid_inputs:
    print(your_input)
else:
    print('over')
```

Comment: YES! This is it! Thank you! Sorry for not explaining it that well guys!

Comment: role = " "
valid_roles = ['male', 'female']

role = input("Are you a male or female? ")
if role in valid_roles:
    print(role)
else:
    print("over")